# How to cancel a completion in zsh prezto in vi insert mode?

Tags: zsh, vi, prezto

In zsh, with emacs key mapping mode, <kbd>Control + _</kbd> will cancel a completion.

Example:

```
echo $EDITOR[tab]
```

will be completed as:

```
echo vim
```

Pressing <kbd>Control + _</kbd> will restore the editor to:

```
echo $EDITOR
```

I want to do the same thing with vi key mapping mode.
Is there a way to do it? Is there already a key mapping to do it?
<kbd>Control + _</kbd> does not work neither in insert mode nor in normal mode.

The <kbd>u</kbd> (undo) will remove the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do it.

```
bindkey -l will print a list of existing keymap names.
bindkey -M <keymap> will list all bindings for a given keymap.
```

So I compared emacs and viins bindings and added the following line:

```
bindkey -M viins "$key_info[Control]_" undo
```

to the `.zprezto/modules/editor/init.zsh`. And it works.

I made a pull request to add this mapping to prezto:
https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/pull/1860